# Variance of $U= a \log (Z+b)-Z$ where $Z$ is the exponential random variable

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Consider a random variable
\begin{align}
U= a \log (Z+b)-Z
\end{align}
where $a,b>0$ and $Z$ is an exponential random variable.

**Question:** Can we find the variance of $U$?

**Things that I tried**

Because of the log, the direct computation doesn't seem possible (at least to me).
Here is what I tried, let
\begin{align}
f(Z)=  a \log (Z+b)-Z
\end{align}
then using the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that
\begin{align}
Var( f(Z) )&= Var \left( \int_0^Z f'(x) dx \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}E \left[ \left(  \int_0^Z f'(x) dx -  \int_0^{Z'} f'(x) dx \right)^2 \right]
\end{align}
where in the last step we have use that $Var(W)= \frac{1}{2} E[(W-W')^2]$ where $W'$ is and independent copy of $W$.
Now, we have that
\begin{align}
Var( f(Z) ) &= \frac{1}{2}E \left[ \left(  \int_{Z'}^Z f'(x) dx  \right)^2 \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}E \left[  \int_{Z'}^Z \int_{Z'}^Z f'(x_1)  f'(x_2) dx_1 dx_2   \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}E \left[  \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty f'(x_1)  f'(x_2) 1_{\{ Z' \le x_1 \le Z \cap Z' \le x_1 \le Z  \}}  dx_1 dx_2   \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}  \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty f'(x_1)  f'(x_2) E \left[ 1_{\{ Z' \le x_1 \le Z \cap Z' \le x_1 \le Z  \}}  \right]  dx_1 dx_2  
\end{align}
I didn't verify the exchange of integration but I think it's ok. Now,
\begin{align}
E \left[ 1_{\{ Z' \le x_1 \le Z \cap Z' \le x_1 \le Z  \}}  \right]&=
\mathbb{P}[  Z' \le x_1 \le Z \cap Z' \le x_1 \le Z ]\\
&=\mathbb{P}[  Z' \le \min(x_1,x_2) \cap  \max(x_1,x_2) \le Z ]\\
&= \left( 1-e^{-\min(x_1,x_2)} \right)  e^{-\max(x_1,x_2)} 
\end{align}
where we have used independence and the fact that $Z$ is exponential. Putting everything together that using that $f'(x)=\frac{a}{x+b}-1$, we have that
\begin{align}
&Var( f(Z) ) \notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}  \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty  \left( \frac{a}{x_1+b}-1 \right)   \left( \frac{a}{x_2+b}-1 \right) \left( 1-e^{-\min(x_1,x_2)} \right)  e^{-\max(x_1,x_2)}   dx_1 dx_2  
\end{align}

However, I could not finish this integral.

Comment: Would an approximation of the variance be sufficient? You can use Taylor series for that.

Comment: The wisdom of @Eli's comment is apparent when you examine a closed form formula for the variance.  It depends on two exponential integral values, an incomplete Gamma value, and a MeijerG function (of $b$).  The latter becomes negligible for largish $b$ (greater than $3$ or so).

Comment: @Eli Sure, but I only if we have a guarantee on the approximation error.  That is we can show that $ |V- \hat{V}| \le c$ where $c$ is a function of $a$ and $b$ and where $\hat{V}$ is the approximation of the variance $V$.

Comment: @whuber It might depend on what software the OP has available (assuming that the variance is being evaluated for particular values of the parameters).  I get a form just a little more simple than what you describe (an incomplete gamma and a generalized hypergeometric:  $\frac{1}{6} a e^{b \lambda } \left(-12 a b \lambda  \, _3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-b \lambda )+a \left(6 \log (b \lambda ) (\log (b \lambda )+2 \gamma )+6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right)+12 b \Gamma (0,b \lambda )\right)-a^2 e^{2 b \lambda } \Gamma (0,b \lambda )^2-\frac{2 a}{\lambda }+\frac{1}{\lambda ^2}$.

Comment: @JimB. What is $\lambda$ in your expression? Parameter of the exponential?

Comment: Yes. And $\gamma$ is the Euler $\gamma$ constant.

Comment: Why are you looking at this function? And what would be typical values of $a$, $b$, and $E[Z]$ in your application?

Comment: @JimB Yes, that looks right: I get the same kind of expression after applying `FunctionExpand` to my result.  (I obtained it indirectly by computing derivatives of the characteristic function.)